# Is there an autoexit for cmd.exe like there is an autorun?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-registry, cmd.exe, autorun

In windows when you create a value `autorun` in registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` and set it to, say, `echo Hello from autorun`, invoking cmd.exe will, on invocation, first execute that line.

Is there an equivalent `autoexit`-like value to run on closing cmd.exe?

I have tried `autoexit, autoclose, autoquit, exit, onexit, onquit` and `quit` with no luck.

What I want to achieve is to save the current directory on exit of `cmd.exe` by  setting the (imaginary) `autoexit` registry value to `setx _LAST_DIR "%cd%"`, so that I can recall it on next invocation with `cd "%_LAST_DIR%"` or in a `Command prompt Last Dir.lnk` file with the `Start in` input box set to `%_LAST_DIR%`.

My current solution is to have a batch file in the `PATH`, `myexit.cmd`:

```bat
@setx _LAST_DIR "%CD%"
@exit
```

that I have to remember to invoke instead of exit, if I want to save the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do doesn't actually require what you're asking and doesn't work with the workaround provided, so I've split this into two parts.

## Saving the last used directory to an environment variable

Create a batch file with the following:

```
@CD /D %*
@>nul setx _LAST_DIR "%CD%"
```

Set your AutoRun to the following:

```
CD /D %_LAST_DIR%&doskey cd=@ECHO off$T<FILENAME> $*$T@ECHO on
```

Where `<FILENAME>` is the **full path** to the batch file you just created. Alternatively, create the batch file in a directory listed in your `PATH` variable so you can just use the filename.

The breakdown:

- This is multiple commands, separated by the `&` character, which allows commands to be run in sequence.
- `CD /D %_LAST_DIR%` will change the directory to the contents of the `_LAST_DIR` environment variable. The `/D` switch is used to allow changing to a directory on a different drive.
- `doskey cd=@ECHO off$T<FILENAME> $*$T@ECHO on` creates a `DOSKEY` macro that does several things.

  - `doskey cd=` will create a macro that replaces the default CD command
  - `$T` is the `DOSKEY` equivalent of `&` and is used to separate multiple commands. `$*` is the `DOSKEY` equivalent to `%*` and holds all of the arguments passed to the macro.
  - The macro will turn off `ECHO` for less clutter, change the directory, set the environment variable and then turn `ECHO` back on.
  - Since we're using a batch file inside the `DOSKEY` macro, we can use the `%CD%` variable to give us the full directory path and account for errors.

**Further reading:**

- [Doskey - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html)

## Autoexit

This portion doesn't do what you want, but others using similar search terms may find it useful.

As far as I can find, this option doesn't exist and isn't mentioned in [Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc779439(v%3Dws.10)). Here is a potential work around.

**Warning:** Do not use this code if you don't understand it as you could end up with an infinite loop of command prompts starting. This should be **thoroughly** tested before being used in any sort of production environment.

Create a batch file with the following code and set it as your AutoRun:

```
@cls
@cmd /d
<exit commands here>
@exit
```

The breakdown:

- The `@` character at the start of each line, as you already know, will hide the commands themselves and show only any output. This is to reduce clutter.
- `cls` will clear the header containing the Windows version and copyright information. If you want to clear it from *both* consoles, you can replace the next command with `cmd /d /k`.
- `@cmd /d` will start a new (child) command prompt inside this one and keep it open for you to run whatever commands you choose. The `/D` switch tells the command prompt *not* to use the AutoRun.
- When the child command prompt exits, it will continue running this batch file.
- `<exit commands here>` should be replaced with whatever commands you want to run. This will not be able to access any environment variables or variable changes that are local to the child command prompt. Even `SETX` will only apply to future command prompts, but not be passed back to the parent command prompt.

**Note:** If the command prompt is terminated abnormally (by clicking the red X in the window or by ending it's task in Task Manager), it will not run your exit commands.

**Further reading:**

- [Autorun - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-autoexec.html)
- [Cmd - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

Comment: Don't think it works. `cmd /d` starts a new child shell and on return the parent shells `%CD%` is restored to where it was before calling `cmd /d`.

Comment: Does not save the full path, only the name of the current directory.
So assuming cd = C:\USers\Henrik\     `cd test_lastdir&&exit` works, but `cd test_lastdir\subdir&&exit` fails.

Comment: Rev. 7 now seems to work except for directories with spaces in them.Just need to enclose %CD% in double quotes in the batch file. Great work  Worthwelle. Wasn't allowed to do it myself as the system requires a minimum of 6 characters of change and the change was only 2.

Comment: Of course this only works when using cd. Other tools that might change directory, like pushd/popd or 3rd. party tools won't work.

Comment: Edit of my previous comment.
I would vote your answer up if I could. (less than 15 reputation). Regarding a backdraw of this solution,- this only works when using cd. Other tools that might change directory, like pushd/popd or 3rd. party tools won't work. But it's an ok compromise for emulating bash's `.bash_logout` which actually was what I was searching for. I'll accept the solution when the change `s/%CD%/"%CD%"/` is added. Thx a bunch for the work and effort.
PS. What is that stupid rule that comment only can be edited for 5 minutes.?